# iPhone Jailbreaking and Unlocking

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, crash, unlock

What exactly does jailbreaking and unlocking doing to an iPhone?

I'm aware that hackers are using baseband crashes for unlocking, but how are they exploiting these crashes? Even if they inject their code into memory, how they are keeping it even after a reboot?

How these guys finding the crashes? Can I find the crash log too?

As an iPhone developer, I'm interested in some technical answers.

I've gone through some interesting links from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668867/what-does-jailbreak-do-to-the-iphone-technically), but haven't found anything about how the hackers are doing it (especially unlocking).

Any references will be extremely useful.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't allowed. "Grey Area" Rules. See http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2/can-one-ask-hackintosh-questions-on-apple-beta

Comment: @VxJasonxV We don't allow Hackintosh questions, but we do allow [jailbreaking questions](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15/should-be-allow-jailbroken-hardware-questions)

Comment: I searched for "jailbreak" on meta, no surprise I didn't find "jailbroken". That's aggravating. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This question should be closed *only* because it isn't properly wrote, the title is as vague as it can be and the content contains lots of unclear questions.

Answer (score 4):

Jailbreaking is the process of hacking the code signing mechanism to allow unsigned code to run on the phone. There are multiple tools used for this and they vary between both model and iOS version.

Unlocking is the process of hacking the 3G chip's baseband to allow SIM cards from other networks without an official unlock from the carrier. There's also an alternative method called Subscriber Artificial Module (SAM) which creates a fake but slightly more authentic unlock from iTunes. I have never needed a hacked unlock (Australia has official carrier unlocks) so I don't know much more about it. Unlocking naturally needs a jailbreak to work, which is why the two are sometimes confused.

If you want a more technical answer you'll need to specify one or the other, as jailbreaking and unlocking are two entirely different types of hacks.

I'd also advise against trying anything you don't completely understand because if you don't know what you're doing you're liable to make irreversible changes to your phone, especially when tampering with the baseband.

Comment: Im curious knowing more about unlocking,how can i find the baseband crash logs?

Comment: As I mentioned, I have no idea. Try posting a comment on the Dev Team blog. You better be 200% sure of anything you do to your baseband, because changes to it are irreversible. I cannot stress enough how much of an unwise idea it is to casually poke around at baseband hacking.

Answer (score 1):

Jailbreak allows installation of non apple approved apps. 
Unlock allows you to use iPhone with another cell phone company.

Comment: That didn't meaningfully cover anything the OP asked.

Comment: @VxJasonxV - The OP asked "What exactly is Jailbreaking and unlocking doing to an iPhone ?" @Zote answered that.

Comment: No, the OP said "What exactly is Jailbreaking and unlocking doing to an iPhone?" The OP did NOT say "What will Jailbreaking and unlocking allow me to do?" The OP is asking for things like what the SHAtter exploit does, what signture falsifying/checksum disabling is going on, etc. etc. etc. Emphasis on the fourth line: "As an iPhone developer, I'm interested in some **technical answers**." (Emphasis mine.)  Also note my own words. *Meaningfully* cover. The OP is asking for details, he got peanuts instead.

Comment: If the OP wanted technical questions he should have asked specifically about *either* Jailbreaking *or* unlocking, as these are two rather separate processes to do to the phone. I've Jailbroken an iPhone 3G and an iPhone 4, but I've never unlocked them because I've never needed an unofficial unlock.